# Ajax request not working the callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var requestURL = 'http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons?callback=?';
    $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
     url: requestURL,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
```

This is my code, 
I honestly have no clue, and i have been trying to find the answer online, and looking at other peoples code, and i just don't know. Probably the answer is really dumb, but anyways, in order to do more stuff with the data, i really need to pass by this situation.
So, i have this code, which i want to interpreter the values into different things in Html, but for doing that, i need the value. I know that im doing a positive request because i can see in the response. But it looks like the success function is not triggered. 
I just want to know why i cant see in the console, all the data that is pulling from this json file. 
Thank you, and sorry if you guys think that this question is too dumb :(

Comment: It looks like a cross domain request... so have a look at Same Origin Policy restrictions and how to resolve them

Comment: its looks like cross-origin/ CORS based issue

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I can make the request, it turns 200 successful, what i can't do is use the data. I am not having troubles making the call .. im having troubles making this call actually do something.. i mean, show in the console.

Comment: The data returned is not properly wrapped in a callback function as jsonp data should be: `myCallback({[.......]});`

Answer (score 1):

Comment dataType like below and try this.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var requestURL = 'http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons?callback=?';
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
// dataType: 'json',           // comment datatype 
 url: requestURL,
success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You want to start by making sure that the server is returning a proper jsonp response since you're calling cross-domain. Then you have to use `dataType:'jsonp'`. And you do not need a success or complete callback; you do need a callback function which will be called once the data is returned.

```js
function myCallback( data ) {
  $('pre.out').text( JSON.stringify(data) );
};
$(document).ready(function(){

    var requestURL = 'http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons?callback=?';
    $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonpCallback: 'myCallback',
     url: requestURL
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```

If you check the network tab of dev tools, you should see data returned but it is not properly wrapped in a callback function as jsonp should.

**SERVER RESPONSE:**

```
[{"id":351,"caption":"1. Bundesliga 2014/15",...."lastUpdated":"2014-11-03T03:58:10Z"}]
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a simple example where the server is sending proper jsonp:

```js
$.ajax( 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&callback=?', {
  dataType:'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback:'myCallback'
});
function myCallback( data ) {
    $('pre.out').text( JSON.stringify(data) );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```

**SERVER RESPONSE:**

```
 myCallback({"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},"sys"....."cod":200});
```

Comment: JSON is for same domain consumption. When you're fetching **CROSS-DOMAIN**, you need **JSONP**.

Comment: is there a work around for me to get the data while working locally?

Comment: Hopefully by locally you mean on your own domain. You can write a server-side script on your server (proxy) to fetch the data. Then you would just need to call that proxy which will be on the same domain as your page and therefore you would not need JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,this may Work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var requestURL = 'http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons?callback=?';
        $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'json',
         url:'requestURL'}). success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is using the format of promise but the result should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Did your console say it's a cross origin request? If so, you probably need to use jsonp or a proxy.

**EDITED**

Remove dataType: 'json', and it should work

Reason is that you have a callback in your url and jquery is smart enough to detect it. but the callback is not called so it errors. you should also define an error handler. if you remove dataType jquery will auto detect the data type hence it works.

Comment: the console doesnt say anything. The response tab shows that the request was successfull

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

dataType: jsonp for cross-domain request, that means request to different domain and dataType: json for same domain-same origin request.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is two parts. The first is a parse error stemming from the JSON tag. If you remove the JSON datatype from your request, the error you will see is a cross site scripting error. See code below (if you use complete to print out to the console, you will get information every time. You should also look into using breakpoints)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("doc ready");
    var requestURL = 'http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons?callback=?';
    $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: requestURL,
     complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        console.log(textStatus);
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: ok, so with your answer it managed to print to the console the textStatus, but how do i get the data? I am really beginner on this subject, so if you could point a direction on what should I do, i would appreciate, thank you anyways.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't worked with cross site scripting so I can't really help you out further :/ I would recommend either starting a new question about cross-site scripting or trying to find a previous question about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue you are facing but as others mentioned it look like a CORS issue.I wrote a post on CORS [here](http://aameer.github.io/articles/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/) which explains about CORS and shows ajax example too.A CORS GET request through ajax would look like this:

```
ajaxOptsCrossOrigin = {
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, //adds cookies, credentials
    url: "https://"+server_name+"/get_link/",
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: data_vals,
    success: function(resp){
        //do something on success
    },
};
jQuery.ajax(ajaxOptsCrossOrigin);
//In your case:
ajaxOptsCrossOrigin = {
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}, //adds cookies, credentials
    url: "http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons?callback=?",
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    //data: data_vals,
    success: function(resp){
        //do something on success
        alert(data);
    },
};
jQuery.ajax(ajaxOptsCrossOrigin);
```

Note the server you are interacting with should be CORS enabled.Hope it helps

Comment: I appreciate your help Aameer, but i am totally lost.

Comment: try the second ajax call in my answer , check if that works for you @RenanCidale

Comment: I tried and still doesnt show anything, It doesnt have the error of Cross Origin, but it doesnt show anything, i tried to put console.log(resp), and nothing.

Comment: do you have access to the back-end to which you are sending the request?

Comment: is open. if you go to the site, http://www.football-data.org/soccerseasons , you can see all of the JSON all nice and neat, i just want to extract them and work on the html dynamically

Comment: Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: if you have access to the server then all you need is to enable CORS and add your new domain to it , if not then you may have to do some extra work like saving this html file and the parsing through the html and get the Json although I never tried such thing but you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it will not be working is because the football-api does not return jsonp. It does however use CORS (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing). There is some sample code on the website. I have given the sample code below and created a fiddle for you. All you have to do is replace the text [ENTER API KEY HERE!] with the key that you were emailed. (If you do not yet have a API key just go to the site and click "free API Key" and enter your email. They will send you one.

Once you enter the key click run within the fiddle and you will see a list of fixtures.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Boldonglen/jwvozp57/)

```
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-Auth-Token':'[ENTER API KEY HERE!]' },
            url: 'http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/fixtures?timeFrame=n7',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
        }).done(function(response) {   
            var regex = /.*?(\d+)$/; // the ? makes the first part non-greedy
            var fixtureTable = "";
            console.log(response);

            fixtureTable += "<table>";

            $.each(response.fixtures, function(i,v){
                fixtureTable += "<tr><td>"+v.homeTeamName+"</td><td><strong>VS</strong></td><td style='text-align:right;'>"+v.awayTeamName+"</td><td>"+$.format.date(v.date, "ED MMM yyyy hh:mma")+"</td></tr>";
            });

            fixtureTable += "</table>";

            $('#fixtureTable').html(fixtureTable);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign up in order to obtain the API token and use it like below:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR API TOKEN' },
  url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/440/fixtures?timeFrame=n20',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
}).done(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
})
```